# EF Core/C#: Set many-to-many relationship with a variable field?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

If you have an EF/asp.net Core app that has ads with services with a price. Where each ad can have many services (out of a predefined set of choices, like haircut, nail polish, etc. ) and a price that is variable for each ad.  How do you form the many to many relationship?

```cs
public class Ad {
 ...
 ...
// the list of serviceTypes to choose from to add to your Ad.
 public List<ServiceType> Services { get; set; )
}

public class ServiceType {
...
 public string ServiceName { get; set; }
 // I can't set price here since every ad has its own price (varying) for the given serviceType!
public List<Ad> Ad { set; get; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is no longer a many to many relationship between two entities that EF can implicitly handle for you, but rather two one to many relationships between three entities.

Create an intermediary `AdServiceType` (or any other appropriate name) which has two FKs (`Ad`, `ServiceType`) and the price field. The `AdServiceType` then acts as the joined relationship between your ads and your service types.

Answer (score 1):

Based [@Flater](https://stackoverflow.com/users/952296/flater) answer you should create an intermediate class:

```
public class Ad
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    // the list of serviceTypes to choose from to add to your Ad.
    public ICollection<AdServiceType> AdServiceTypes { get; set; } = new HashSet<AdServiceType>();
}

public class ServiceType
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string ServiceName { get; set; }
    
    // I can't set price here since every ad has its own price (varying) for the given serviceType!
    public ICollection<AdServiceType> AdServiceTypes { set; get; } = new HashSet<AdServiceType>();
}

public class AdServiceType
{
    public long AdId { set; get; }
    public long ServiceTypeId { set; get; }
    public Ad Ad { set; get; }
    public ServiceType Service { set; get; }
}
```